# Entity framework [Required] attribute on relationships behaves differently when used in seed method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using EF code first with automatic migrations enabled.

I have below entities.

```
public class Order
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BranchId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("BranchId")]
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
public class Branch 
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my seed on Configuration.cs and it works fine when I run Update-Database command via package manager console.

```
protected override void Seed(DataAccessLayer.ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    Branch branch = db.Branch.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1); // Id = 1 already exists in the table
    Order order = new Order()
    {
      BranchId = branch.Id
    }
    db.Order.Add(order);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I use above code in a normal class it throws an Entity Framework validation error

```
private void AddOrder()
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
      Branch branch = db.Branch.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1); // Id = 1 already exists in the table
      Order order = new Order()
      {
        BranchId = branch.Id
      }

      db.Order.Add(order);
      db.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Above gives below error

```
ErrorMessage = "The Branch field is required."
```

So when I change above to below code with additional two lines it works fine

```
private void AddOrder()
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
      Branch branch = db.Branch.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1); // Id = 1 already exists in the table
      Order order = new Order()
      {
        BranchId = branch.Id
        Branch = branch
      }

      db.Entry(branch).State = EntityState.Unchanged; // needed to avoid duplicating branch information
      db.Order.Add(order);
      db.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

It makes sense why the validation error due to obvious reasons, but my question is why is this not enforced in the seed method?

I'd prefer to use the code same as from seed method in my other classes, is there a way to achieve this ?